# How to delete a link between a GitHub repository and the previous name of the repository?

Tags: github, rename

On GitHub I have a [`funtoo-config`](https://github.com/fusion809/funtoo-config) repository and it links to [`gentoo-config`](https://github.com/fusion809/gentoo-config) (which was its previous name), is there a way to delete the `gentoo-config` link so that I am free to create a new repository named `gentoo-config`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merely had to ask the GitHub staff to do this for me via the contact form. 'tis fixed now.